# Timer Elapsed event handler, can't run specific code inside it

Tags: c#, event-handling, timer, nullreferenceexception

I have some weirdness going on here.

I have a void like this

```
private void Filter()
{
    MyDataView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", tb_Filter.Text);
}
```

Then I have a timer elapsed event handler and it's method just looks like this

```
void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Filter();
}
```

I put **timer.AutoReset** to false and put **timer.Start()** inside an eventhandler for a button.
I click the button, nothing happens. It just hangs for a while and then spews this out:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

If I run the **Filter()** method from inside any other eventhandler (button_click, textchanged, whatever) it runs fine.
If I put any other code inside the timer_Elapsed event handler, before calling Filter(), it will run. For example:

```
    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this works");
    }
```

will print "this works" to the console when the timer elapses.

I'm baffled. What am I doing wrong here?
Why does my Filter() method be run on any event except timer_elapsed?

**EDIT:** Got a more detailed exception:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different >thread owns it.

Comment: A Threading exception? Is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: Well, the point of this timer was to put a delay on a textbox.textchanged eventhandler. I wanted to be able to filter this dataview that is bound to a datagrid in real time as the user types in textbox, but it was a little slow, so I was gonna put a small delay on the filter method after the user stops typing. I guess the timer runs on it's own thread, idk. But I figured it out, I use a dispatchertimer instead and it seems to be working.

Comment: Can barely see something wrong, a few more details will be great

Comment: If you're using `System.Timers.Timer`, then you need to set the `SynchronizingObject` so that the `Elapsed` event handler is called on the UI thread.  An alternative is to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or the equivalent WPF timer (the name of which I always forget).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elapsed event handler runs on a threadpool thread.  That's poison to the RowFilter property, assigning it is going to cause the control to be updated.  That can only be done on the UI thread, user interface components are never thread-safe.

Use a regular Winforms Timer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that an exception is being thrown?  I would usually enable the Debug -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions option and try again.

Comment: I got some more details from that.  I'll edit the first post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your timer_Elapsed handler gets launched in a thread, different from the UI one. This means that you may perform thread-independent actions (like printing to Console) from there, but you'll fail if you attempt to access UI objects.

You can read about these issues here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx
As a quick solution, you might replace your

```
MyDataView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", tb_Filter.Text);
```

with something like

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { MyDataView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", tb_Filter.Text); }));
```